# query for 'ticket activity' in osTicket database

Tags: mysql, osticket

[ticket activity osTicket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zBay.png)

how can i get data like that table, from database osTicket?

Comment: What does your question have to do with MySQL?  Can you show sample input data in the form of a formatted _table_?

Comment: yes i need get data with MySQL but i don't have knowledge about osTicket database

Comment: ...and you expect that we would have this knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of data on the picture. Which of them do you want exactly? I have a few queries for osticket usage stats.

For example: This query retrieves count of opened tickets by date, that have specific helptopic "topicname".

```
SELECT DATE(ticketTbl.created), count(*) 
FROM osticketdb.ost_ticket AS ticketTbl
    INNER JOIN osticketdb.ost_help_topic AS topicTbl
    ON ticketTbl.topic_id = topicTbl.topic_id
WHERE topicTbl.topic = 'topicname'
GROUP BY DATE(ticketTbl.created);
```